# Java - Flight Schedule [university's homework]

Tags: java, time, int, final

I'm supposed to program a flight schedule and ran into a little problem.

The user has to insert: 
Departure Day (1 - 7, when 1 means the first day of the week and 7 the last day of the week).
Departure Hour (0 - 24).
Departure Minute (0 - 60).

Then :
Flight's length in hours.
Flight's length in minutes.

Then :
The user gets the arrival time according to the data he/she inserted above.

For some reason, if I enter :

### Departure time : Day 1, Hour 10, Minute 00.

Flight's length in hours 72 hours.
Flight's length in minutes 00 minutes.

What I'm supposed to get is : Day 4, Hour 10, Minute 00.
What I get is : Day 1, Hour 49, Minute 10.

-- EDIT --
Here's the new code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Flight
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter flight day: ");
        int FLYDAY = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter flight hour: ");
        int FLYHOUR = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter flight minute: ");
        int FLYMINUTE = scan.nextInt();

        int departureDay = scan.nextInt();
        int departureHour = scan.nextInt();
        int departureMin = scan.nextInt();

        departureMin += FLYMINUTE;
        while(departureMin >= 60) {
            departureHour++;
            departureMin-=60;
        }

        departureHour += FLYHOUR;
        while(departureHour >= 24)
        {
            departureDay++;
            departureHour-=24;
        }

        while(departureDay >=8)
        departureDay-=7;

        System.out.println("the supposed arrival time is: day- " + departureDay + ", hour- " + departureHour + ", minute- " + departureMin);
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely your target answer should be Day 4?

Comment: Departure hour 0-60 ? Shouldn't it be 0-24 ? There is only 24 hours in  a day.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I meant 0 - 24. I'm lacking of sleep (It's 3 am here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your if-statements to while-statements. For example, write

```
while(departureMin >= 60) {
    departureHour++;
    departureMin-=60;
}
```

Additionally, your user input section is very wonky. A better way would be:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("Enter flight day: ");
int FLYDAY = scan.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter flight hour: ");
int FLYHOUR = scan.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter flight minute: ");
int FLYMINUTE = scan.nextInt();
```

Follow the same format for asking how long the flight should last.

Comment: There is another problem as well.

Comment: I did, I can notice the results have changed, yet not 100% accurate, I appreciate it though and thank you :D and when I enter the same as above, it gives me Day 3, Hour 1, minute 10. Why does it even give me minute 10? I just put 72 hours and 0 minutes flight length. lol

Comment: @EladAlice Can you edit your question to include the newly changed code?

Comment: Thank you so much!! it works now, a quick question: let's say I wanna remove the "flight's length in days" and follow only flight's length in hours and minutes? Do I have to remove the flight's length in days and change all the 'while's? and yeah I'll change the code in my question.

Comment: @EladAlice You could do that by simply removing all portions of code which refer to the flight's length in days (and the corresponding user inputs).

Comment: @JaredNielsen I accepted your answer as accepted :) and I tried to remove every code associated with the flight's length in days, it messed up all my project lol, I ctrl + z'ed. if I remove the int departureDay = scan.nextInt(); it messes up everything and the results are all unclear.

Comment: nvm it works now, I got it to work through the first ints you gave me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you kindly noted this as homework, I will not tell you the answer (although I noted two general types of errors plus some style issues), instead I will give you some tools to find the problems yourself.

First, for something this simple, try pretending to be the computer. To do this

1. Write the variable names across the rows on a sheet of paper.
2. Go through each line and see if you can figure out how the variables change.

If that doesn't work (sometimes the problem is that your understanding of what the computer does is wrong), then you can print the variables (a) after they are all read and (b) between each set of conditional.  To do this copy the System.println command (possibly with modifications) after the variables are read and after each conditional.

Hopefully that will help you find the answer.

Comment: Thank you for being very kind giving me a useless answer. I still don't get it, I'm not a java expert, I'm still a beginner, it's my first java course @ uni :(

Comment: I'll edit to be more specific.  You need to know these tricks if you ever want to know how to program (even experience programmers regularly display variables).

Comment: Also, for any words you don't know, ask about them -- (a) it will help me be clearer in the future and (b) other readers will learn as well.

Comment: Thanks :P now it's more useful~